# C# Testing for valid Word Document before opening it

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to work with Microsoft word document. The trouble is when I rename an image to the file extension .doc and then call the com object as follows it hangs. There must be a way to test if the file is a valid word document before attempting to open it. Anyone have an answer?

```
ApplicationClass.Documents.Open(ref path,
                                ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I decided to use Aspose: http://www.aspose.com/

It turns out this is very powerful and simple to use. It throws an exception when a document is not in the correct format which can be caught and handled.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the if document exists with

(System.IO.File.Exists((string)fileName))
        {

}
and since the path is a string you can use a substring for the last 3 - 4 signs.
Or you can split it with the delimiter '.'
And that should give you the first and last part.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the first handful of bytes in the file, check out the [Word 97/8 file format](http://www.wotsit.org/getfile.asp?file=wword8&sc=344037410) - especially the section on the content of the FIB (file information block).  .docx files will need different handling of course.